# Most efficient way to generate Products CSV

Tags: magento-1, api, multistore, products, csv

I am trying to generate a product CSV to upload into a third party CRM

The below code needs to grab the `SKU`, `QTY`, `PRICE` etc for each store in Magento. The problem is when it comes to large collections the script gets stuck, when I have it on a schedule to run every 5 or so minutes.

Can anyone advise on what I can do to make this function more efficiently please?

```
public function getOffersToUpload()
{
    //Get the productIds
    $productIds = $this->getStoreProducts(array(), true);

    //Check if we should include price column in store feed
    $storePrice = Mage::getStoreConfigFlag('marketplace/offer_settings/upload_offer_price');


    //Create the product.csv file
    $csvFilename = 'product.csv';
    $exportDir = Mage::getBaseDir() . '/var/products/' . $csvFilename;

    if (count($productIds) > 0) {

        $products = Mage::getModel('catalog/product');

        $stores = Mage::app()->getStores();

        foreach ($stores as $key => $store) {

            $storeId = $store->getId();

            if (Mage::getStoreConfigFlag('modulename/configuration/active', $storeId)) {

                //Unegister the shopId for each loop
                Mage::unregister('shop_id');

                //Create the array
                $products_row = array();
                $header = array('sku', 'product-id', 'product-id-type', 'price', 'discount-price', 'discount-from-date', 'discount-to-date', 'quantity', 'state');

                $products_row[] = $header; // CSV header

                $csv = new Varien_File_Csv();
                foreach ($productIds as $productId) {
                    $prod = $products->setStoreId($storeId)->load($productId);
                    $data['sku'] = $prod->getSku();
                    $data['product-id'] = $prod->getSku();
                    $data['product-id-type'] = 'SHOP_SKU';
                    $data['price'] = $offerPrice ? round($prod->getPrice()) : "";
                    $data['discount-price'] = $prod->getSpecialPrice();
                    $data['discount-from-date'] = $prod->getSpecialFromDate();
                    $data['discount-to-date'] = $prod->getSpecialToDate();
                    $data['quantity'] = round($prod->getStockItem()->getQty());
                    $data['state'] = '11';

                    $products_row[] = $data;

                }
                //write to csv file
                $csv->saveData($exportDir, $products_row);
                Mage::app()->setCurrentStore($store);
                Mage::register('shop_id', $storeId);
                $callApi = Mage::helper('modulename/callapi');
                $callApi->uploadData();

                //Unset the array() after first loop
                unset($products_row);

            }

        }
    } else {
        Mage::log('no product selection specified', null);
    }
}`
```

Comment: try to import product using Dataflow Profile may be it work for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Possible optimization** :

- Load bulk of data (per 1000 for example)
- Do not load product on each foreach, use collection and select only usefull attributes
- Maybe use differential export whereas full export. Export only updated products. The CRM need to be compatible with this approach.
- If you have some memory problems, you may try to use this function on each foreach : *gc_collect_cycles* before call *gc_enable* outside of your foreach.
- Separate file generation and file upload in two crons if your upload is not fast
- Separate cron task for each store

I will edit my answer if you need some precisions to be more accurate.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I only need the products the have a specific attribute value set to yes. Then I need to write to the CSV file every 5 or 10 minutes

Comment: So retrieve your product collection, add your attribute filter and manage a bulk of data with the setPageSize and setCurPage. Check on Google : https://www.atwix.com/magento/working-with-large-collections/ for example.

Comment: The root problem of your code is this line : $prod = $products->setStoreId($storeId)->load($productId); and maybe your custom function getStoreProducts which I do not have the code.